# Tiny Switch TNY289 current limit and di/dt question

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I want to ask about how the Integrated circuit decides the proper (di/dt) for next cycle , the voltage across an inductor/transformer is L*(di/dt)  the Integrated circuit TNY289 as I understand
it ramps up current so that (di/dt) is constant and consequently the voltage across an inductor/transformer is constant during ramp up (on time) , my question does the decision about (di/dt) for next cycle is to maintain constant Voltage on drain constant (Vsupply - L(di/dt)) ?
On what criteria this decision is taken ? to maintain what constant at what value ?

I understand also that the slope should be (di/dt)= Ilimit/Ton , to change (di/dt) does Ilimit only change or Ton also ?

I know the following figures in the datasheet are relevant but I couldn't interpret them properly to answer my questions :

[image]

[image]

One last question also concerning the following figure :

During ramp as I interpreted before (di/dt) is constant which means that voltage across the inductor is constant , while the supply voltage is constant , the result of their subtraction (Vds) should be constant but according to last figure the voltage change linearly with current , so during ramp the voltage should ramp also (not constant) according to the last figure , I feel that is contradictory ... so what am I misunderstanding / not interpreting ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how the Integrated circuit decides the proper (di/dt) for next cycle,
> the voltage across an inductor/transformer is L*(di/dt) the Integrated
> circuit TNY289 as I understand it ramps up current so that (di/dt) is
> constant and consequently the voltage across an inductor/transformer
> is constant during ramp up (on time)*

It doesn't; it contains a MOSFET that when activated puts the DC supply voltage across the transformer's primary magnetization inductance. It is V and L that determine di/dt. It's just the simple inductor equation.

> *to change (di/dt) does Ilimit only change or Ton also?*

No, di/dt is fixed by the inductor equation. The only thing the IC can do is control \$t_{ON}\$. By controlling \$t_{ON}\$ it controls the energy delivered to the secondary of the flyback transformer. That energy is limited by the IC's ability to terminate the \$t_{ON}\$ cycle by measuring the current ramped-up to.

> *but according to last figure the voltage change linearly with current, so during ramp the voltage should ramp also (not constant) according
> to the last figure , I feel that is contradictory ... so what am I
> misunderstanding / not interpreting?*

You can assume that the voltage dropped across the MOSFET (internal to the IC) is a very small fraction of the supply voltage so, in effect, we don't care if this rises a couple of volts. Ideally, we assume it always to be 0 volts and, I recommend you adopt that approach when trying to understand this type of circuit.

Comment: thanks for your answer , do you mean that i should express i(t) in terms of v(t) , the opposite of my imagination , i(t)=(1/L) int v(t) dt , since v(t) is constant then its integration is a ramp ... when that limit is reached it switches of ? ! ... I finally can understand it thanks to your answer :D

Comment: Yes, the ramp is caused by the (near) constant voltage applied to the inductor therefore di/dt is (near) constant and, the IC disengages the inductor when a certain current value has been reached.